# Unable to quit a python script (which is using loop) from terminal using Ctrl+C

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Code is working perfectly** but **How can I quit a script which is using a loop?** Is there any method because `Ctrl+C` did not work. I do not have `Break/Pause` button in my keyboard so I could use it.

```
import pandas as pd

import os
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

from PIL import Image

import requests
from io import BytesIO

import argparse


arg_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(allow_abbrev=True, description='Download images from url in a directory',)

arg_parser.add_argument('-d','--DIR',required=True,
                       help='Directory name where images will be saved')

arg_parser.add_argument('-c','--CSV',required=True,
                       help='CSV file name which contains the URLs')

arg_parser.add_argument('-i','--index',type=int,
                       help='Index number of column which contain the urls')

arg_parser.add_argument('-e','--end',type=int,
                       help='How many images to download')

args = vars(arg_parser.parse_args())


def load_save_image_from_url(url,OUT_DIR,img_name):
    response = requests.get(url)
    img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
    img_format = url.split('.')[-1]
    img_name = img_name+'.'+img_format
    img.save(OUT_DIR+img_name)
    return None


csv = args['CSV']
DIR = args['DIR']

ind = 0
if args.get('index'):
    ind = args['index']

df = pd.read_csv(csv) # read csv
indices = [int(f.split('.')[0]) for f in listdir(DIR) if isfile(join(DIR, f))] # get existing images

print(f'There are already {len(indices)} images present in the directory -{DIR}-')
start = 0
if len(indices):
    start = max(indices)+1 # set strating index
    
end = 5000 # next n numbers of images to download
if args.get('end'):
    end = args['end']

print(f'Downloaded a total of {len(indices)} images upto index: {start-1}. Downloading the next {end} images from -{csv}-')

count = 0
for i in range(start, start+end):
    if count%250==0:
        print(f"Total {start+count-1} images downloaded in directory. {end-count} remaining from the current defined")

    url = df.iloc[i,ind]
    try:
        load_save_image_from_url(url,DIR,str(i))
        count+=1
    except:
        print(f'Error Occured at index: {i}')
        pass
```

I just want to quit the program while running. If I have to quit it, I have to close the terminal but I don't think this is the proper way. How could I quit it "properly" without closing the terminal?

Comment: Try `ctrl+z`. Then to fully close it, run `sudo pkill python`

Comment: Why `load_save_image_from_url` function returns None?

Comment: If you will use this script regularly, you can try putting the main code in a background thread

Comment: Try `except KeyboardInterrupt:`

Comment: @AhmetTavli because all I need to do is to fetch the image and save the image in my directory. I do not have to return anything.

Comment: @ZWang But I think it'll cause some un-saved state error at some point of time like if I kill it while `PIL` is saving the image in directory.

Comment: **Don't use a bare except** The bare except *catches all exceptions*, and you merely pass after that. So instead of `except: ...` use `except Exception as e:` at least...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga What I use multiple `Try-Except` inside the function than in a loop. I think that'll be better, right?

Comment: @Deshwal I'm not sure what you mean. A quick fix would be to catch `Exception`, which will catch almost everything except `KeyboardInterrupt`. You should essentially *never* use  a bare exception, i.e. `except: ...`, always catch *something*

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Could you provide a dummy code of how that would be like. I am using `except Exception as e: print('Error Occured') ; pass `. I want to show that at some index, some error occured but when it is a `keyoard or SytemExit` error, I want the code to exit`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the *KeyboardInterrupt* to exit your application as follows:

```
try:
    ### code that prevented the exit goes here
except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
    print("Forced exit")
    raise
```

Then you can normally exit with **Ctrl+C**

Comment: So what if I want to just say that there has been an error but want to quit if a keyboard error has occured?

Comment: you can use multiple except statement for the same try block where each except catches certain exceptions

Comment: Shouldn't I be using `sys.exit(0)` or something like that? I mean how would my program quit from memory?